# WPICTF 2018, Fri 13 April 2018 at 19:00 UTC, lasts 48 hours

Tags: discussion, ctf

Let's participate in [WPICTF 2018](https://ctf.wpictf.xyz/).

WPICTF is a Jeopardy-style CTF and lasts 48 hours. According to their [website](https://wpictf.xyz/): The CTF should be "beginner friendly". Most challenges were made by WPI students, so they are designed from being extremely easy to extremely difficult.

You can find additional details on the [CTFtime event page](https://ctftime.org/event/600).

---

General info:

- We compete as team sec.se.
- We communicate over [Slack](https://sec-ctf.slack.com/). To get an invitation to the group you can contact any member of the team. (We will need to know an email address to send the invitation to and a reference to your Security.SE profile.)
- For questions, join us in the [public chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz).

Good luck everyone!